# Sequelize: Search substring without case sensitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm receiving a name in my route and i want to search a substring in a string, but without case sensitive. My current code works but it is case sensitive.

```
if(name){
  specifications = {
     ...specifications,
     where: { name: { [Sequelize.Op.substring]: name } }
  }
}
```

I have two records in my table:

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Ementas",
  "tabId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-06-24T19:56:53.116Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-24T19:56:53.116Z",
  "user": null,
  "documents": []
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Eu",
  "tabId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-06-24T19:56:47.324Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-24T19:56:47.324Z",
  "user": null,
  "documents": []
},
```

If i search for '**e**', only the first record is returned, but if i search for '**E**', both are returned

How can i make Op.substring be insensitive?

**ps: I'm using postgres**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iLike` operator instead of `substring`:

```
if(name){
  specifications = {
     ...specifications,
     where: { name: { [Sequelize.Op.iLike]: `%${name}%` } }
  }
}
```